# Authorize a role to Amazon S3 through access point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-s3-access-points

The goal is to limit an Amazon S3 Read-Write (list,get,put,delete) access to a single role and access S3 only through access point, with a bucket policy locked to access point only.

The setup I did so far is

- Delegated a partial (list,get,put,delete) access control of s3 to access point.
- Applied an explicit deny on access point level to limit access to only one role.
- In that role added a policy allowing it to list,get,put,delete through the access point.

but experience `AccessDenied` on any of the mentioned operations

**here is S3 Bucket policy:**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeS3ObjectsReadModifyThroughAccessPointsOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-YYY-ZZZ/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointArn": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeS3ObjectsListThroughAccessPointsOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-YYY-ZZZ",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointArn": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**and here is the access point policy:**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeReadModifyS3ObjectsThroughSpecificRoleOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/object/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX-YYY-ZZZ:role/XXX-YYY-ZZZ"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeListS3ObjectsThroughSpecificRoleOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXX-YYY-ZZZ:role/XXX-YYY-ZZZ"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**and here is the role policy:**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadModifyS3Objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/object/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListS3Objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work - `AccessDenied`. I'm testing with a proper role assumed and for example with this command `aws s3 ls "s3://arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX-YYY-ZZZ:accesspoint/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/"`

What is strange is that if the role policy resources are extended with S3 bucket ARN (like `arn:aws:s3:::XXX-YYY-ZZZ/*` and `arn:aws:s3:::XXX-YYY-ZZZ`) so both access and s3 bucket resources are present **then the access is allowed**. And if remove any of the `accesspoint` resource makes the `AccessDenied` appear again. Can not understand this, seems I'm missing something fundamental, will be very grateful for any pointers in docs or solution/advice.

Comment: I am in the exact same place as you were some months ago. If possible, can you share the working policies? Want to have a look at what am I missing 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**None of your policies actually allows the operations in S3**. You have only denies. So naturally, your role has no permission to access S3. From [docs](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/ap/191628106287/myap?region=ap-southeast-2&tab=permissions):

> Permissions granted in an access point policy are only effective if the underlying bucket also allows the same access.

This means that having `Allow` in your role for access point resources is **not enough**.

> What is strange is that if the role policy resources are extended with S3 bucket

Permissions to access S3 access point are **not a replacement** for actually having permissions to access S3. Thus your role needs both permissions for S3 access point and the actual s3 bucket and objects themself.

Comment: thank you, this helped me to revisited the way how I "delegated" the control access and instead of "Deny" to us "Allow" to simplify this a bit.